# What's a HTTP private proxy?

Tags: http, proxy

From 《HTTP Definitive Guide》:

> private HTTP proxy are not common, but they do exist, especially when running directly on the client computer. Some browser auxiliary products, as well as some ISP services, will run some small proxies directly on the user's PC in order to extend browser features, improve performance, or provide host advertisements for free ISP (Internet Service Provider) services.

how to understand it?
why it can extend the browser features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A private proxy acts as an intermediary between a client and the internet. Applying a private proxy means that one client is exclusively using the dedicated IP address at a given time. When a private proxy is in use, requests run through the proxy server (which masks the client’s original IP address) first, and only then connects to the internet resources to fulfill client’s requests.

Private proxies provide you with the highest level of anonymity,  they are used not only for personal but also for business purposes. While personal use cases usually involve anonymity and you can setup your Chrome browser to use a proxy which will route all traffic via a specific endpoint, business uses are different.

For example, ad verification companies use private proxies to check advertisers’ landing pages anonymously. Or, let’s take travel fare aggregators whose businesses almost entirely depend on private proxies. For travel fare aggregators proxies enable automated data collection of flight company websites, online travel agencies, and other sources without IP blocks or bans.

Comment: Could you explain more about business usages?

Comment: Does the private proxy equals to Forward Proxy?